# Send command to inner shell

Tags: batch-file

I have this program called "Send_Command.exe" which communicates with LG android phones by openning speiacl shell.
The program accepts only one argument - the serial port of the phone.

I wrote batch script which run the "Send_Command.exe", and I want to send commands to the inner shell from the batch.

I tried to create text file contains the inner shell commands, and redirect the input of the shell to the file.

This is my code so far. (shorted version)
The full script with the program is in
[my thread in xda-developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/general/guide-root-lg-firmwares-kitkat-lollipop-t3056951).

```
:: wait for adb cconnection
echo Waiting for device..
adb.exe wait-for-device
echo Device detected!

:: search lg serial port
echo Looking for LG serial port..
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\hardware\devicemap\SERIALCOMM /v \Device\LGANDNETDIAG1 2^>nul') do set "comPath=%%~b"
echo Phone found at %comPath%!

:: enter Download mode. (enterDownload file contain single command 'ENTER' which reboot into download mode. this work fine).
echo Rebooting into Download mode..
Send_Command.exe \\.\%comPath% < enterDownload

:: search lg serial port again, this time device already in Download mode
echo Waiting for device..
set comPath=
:wait-for-download
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\hardware\devicemap\SERIALCOMM /v \Device\LGANDNETDIAG1 2^>nul') do set "comPath=%%~b"
if "%comPath%" == "" goto wait-for-download
echo Phone found at %comPath%!

:: send command to root the device.
:: installRoot file contains list of commands for root the device.
echo Rooting device..
Send_Command.exe \\.\%comPath% < installRoot

:: reboot (leaveDownload file contain single command 'LEAVE' which leave download mode. this work fine).
Send_Command.exe \\.\%comPath% < leaveDownload
```

All works well except this line.

```
Send_Command.exe \\.\%comPath% < installRoot
```

For some reason it's not always work.
I run the same script several times in a row, sometimes he runs the commands in installRoot file, and sometimes he just ignores them. I could not make sense of it.

So I need to find another solution if there is so, how to send list of commands to the shell.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: It depends on how Some_shell.exe works. If it accepts standard input as commands, then you can redirect input to it. "It's not always work" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: It's because I could not myself understand when it works and when not.
I run the same script several times in a row, sometimes he runs the commands and sometimes he just ignores them.
I could not make sense of it.

Comment: Hard to suggest any solution when we don't have Some_shell.exe.

Comment: the thing is, for testing this you will need an lg android device. i will edit the post and give more details.

Comment: I edited the question, i hope now it's better.

Comment: What if you replace `Send_Command.exe` with `adb shell [contents of installRoot]`?  Do you experience the same inconsistency using `adb.exe` to invoke commands as you do using `Send_Command.exe`?  According to the [documentation for adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html), `adb shell command` executes the command on the device, then exits.

Comment: I have a very good knowledge in adb, and I wrote several script using it. the thing is what i'm doing with this script is actally root the phone, and I don't have the permissions to that with adb.. I will have to use **`adb shell "su -c command"`** for those commands.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space after `<` before `installRoot` and the other script you're piping. Just struggled with this today after years of she'll programming in *nix only. Tricky batch files ;)